# How to check if the entered filename contains invalid characters or not

Tags: vb6

How do I check whether the filename entered in a textbox is valid or not?

In a text box I am entering or selecting the path and filename from local machine or remote machine, once I selected the filename then I want to check if the entered file name is has any invalid charcaters.
I cannot give like textbox = “Selected Path”, because I can select a file from local machine or remote machine but the file name is same.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by correct? Does the file has to exist, or does it just have to be a legitimate filename?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you want to do it like this? It would be much more intuitive and easy-to-use if you use the [Common Dialog Control ActiveX](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/11/common-dialog-control/3/) to open the file from a local/remote machine.

EDIT: If you want to check whether the file exists, you can use this function:

```
Function FileExist(file As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Error
    'get the file attributes, and make sure what
    'is being passed isnt a directory
    FileExist = (GetAttr(file) And vbDirectory) = 0
Error:
    'Return False if an error occurs
    FileExist = False
End Function
```

Comment: Not for File exist, I want to check Entered filename is correct or not,

Comment: Need Exit Function above "Error:" - function as typed always returns False.

Answer (score 1):

Edited based on comments posted later:

To check the file name if it's valid or not on windows....

Due to differences in Windows architecture, the definition of a valid file name may vary depending upon the component of the operating system and file system you are dealing with.

NTFS file system is the most generous in naming files. The name may be up to 32,768 Unicode characters long. The name can contain trailing periods, trailing spaces, and two files may have names that differ only in case e.g., README.TXT and readme.txt.

On Win32 subsystem, the name can be at most MAX_PATH characters long (defined in windef.h as 260 characters), may not have trailing dots or spaces, and file names are not case sensitive.

DOS and 16-bit Windows applications are still limited to 8 character filename plus 3 characters extension.

Based on the operating system you can apply conditional checks in your VB code to verify a filename as valid or you can come up with a regular expression to verify a file name. However, if you want to be precise then refer to a book or some other sources for more information on the different constraints on file names.

Comment: Following are the forbidden characters in 8 characters filename plus 3 characters extension filenaming scheme... Note all characters are enclosed in single quotes..                                         ';', '=', '+', '<', '>', '|', '"', '[', ']', '\', '/',                                                               
'''' And following are the forbidden characters in long filenaming scheme... '<', '>', '|', '"', '\', '/', ':', '*', '?'

Answer (score -1):

```
Function FileExists(FilePath as string) as Boolean
   On error goto Err
   Dim smtg
   FileExists=True
   smtg=GetAttr(FilePath)  'Here will cause an error if file is missing, and will go to Err:
   Exit Function
 Err:
   FileExists=True
End Function
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The OP asked how to check if a file name is valid for Windows and contains no illegal characters.

Comment: @Deanna, Sorry for question, but are you spying me? 
Wherever I write smtg, you're there too;)

Comment: No, SO justs lists questions with activity. When you post answers or make changes to 20 posts, then they all appear in the list as active at the same time. I'd reply exactly the same regardless of who posted it.